# chunked file reading using stream_iterator

Tags: c++, io, stl, stream

I recently discovered stream_iterator which is great for reading text files where I want to ignore all the whitespace characters. So, I can read a file into a vector as follows:

```
std::ifstream infile(file path, std::ios::binary);
std::vector<char> vec;
vec.insert(vec.begin(),
           std::istream_iterator<char>(infield),
           std::istream_iterator<char>());
```

This works great and only reads the non-whitespace characters which is what I want. However, I am trying to read the file in chunks and I wonder how one can extend this typical example to read `n` bytes at a time.

BTW: I noticed that this is something special for the stream_iterator. For example, doing:

```
std::vector<char> vec(5);
input_file.read(&vec[0], 5);
```

This does not chomp the whitespace characters.

Unfortunately, I cannot read the whole file at a time and it has to be streamed. Also, I cannot use third library packages and need to stay with the standard library use.

Comment: It is not an option. File is too large to fit in the memory, unfortunately :/

Comment: Ahhhh.... yes but that is not an option either. I should have mentioned that in my post. I will edit it. I need to stay within the standard libraries.

Comment: I have edited the post to be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any standard library algorithm that implements what you want to do. However, it would be trivial to implement it yourself:

```
auto ReadChunk (std::istream &in, std::int64_t chunkSize) {
    std::vector<char> ret;
    ret.reserve(chunkSize);
    for (std::int64_t i = 0; i < chunkSize; ++i) {
        char c;
        if (!(in >> c)) 
            throw std::runtime_error("Fail"); // Or some other error handling
        ret.push_back(c);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This is easy, clear and efficient enough to make it not inferior to any smart library solution IMO.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot the >> operators chomp ws too.